# MySql Insert into the row with the highest ID

Tags: php, mysql

```
    mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM testuser ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1 INSERT INTO testuser (end) 
    VALUES ('$date')");
```

I am trying to select the row that has the highest id and insert a value into the "end" row, the attempt above is what i tried with about .1% knowledge about mysql.

This is what i have:

```
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO testuser (end) 
    VALUES ('$date')");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO testuser (end) 
SELECT end
FROM testuser
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If end column keep variable you want to insert.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert it will always insert after the highest id row.

I am little confused. It seems that you are trying to update the highest id row.
 if so then try :

```
mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE testuser SET `end` = '$date' WHERE
   id= SELECT id FROM testuser ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

or you can do it like this:

```
 mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE testuser SET `end` = '$date' WHERE
       id= SELECT MAX(id) FROM testuser");
```

Comment: I want to insert into the highest id row, 

example I want to select the id 2 (highest id) and insert into it's end row

Comment: what do you mean by its end row ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO  testuser (end) 
                            SELECT end FROM testuser ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Will this select the right stuff first and then add the value? is that how this works?

Comment: There is a race condition in your code - what if two processes clash?

Comment: Your edited answer is now identical to Nebojsa Susic

Comment: I edited because mapping two separate query into single query.